# Need some help analyzing Android catlogs to solve constant crashes

Tags: android

I am an owner of a Lenovo K2; due to having a lot of reboots and application crashes, I flashed the official Lenovo Nougat ROM from their recovery tool, performed system factory reset, cleared cache of everything...

Doing so did not resolve the problem at all, so I replicated the crashes and reboots while logging via adb logcat (treshold level Warning).

Here is the complete log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9955zdinyemezx/log4.txt?dl=0

I am no expert so I'd appreciate if someone could help me analyse the log I'd be very thankful; here are the most recurring errors:

```
07-22 19:34:36.375  5135  5135 W PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to package com.lenovo.leos.cloud.sync.row because it was previously installed without


07-22 19:34:36.375  5135  5135 W PackageManager: Unknown permission android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER in package com.lenovo.leos.cloud.sync.row

07-22 19:34:39.504  5135  5135 E DeviceIdleController: Bad device idle settings
07-22 19:34:39.504  5135  5135 E DeviceIdleController: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'null' in 'null' is not a valid key-value pair
```

And Fatal exceptions thrown when apps crash:

```
07-22 19:33:56.796  1422  1516 F art     : art/runtime/gc/collector/mark_sweep.cc:413] Tried to mark 0x40 not contained by any spaces

07-22 19:34:28.815  4933  4933 F DEBUG   : pid: 665, tid: 665, name: fingerprintd  >>> /system/bin/fingerprintd <<<
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a consulting/design/coding service, web search replacement nor user support forum. Your question is quite off-topic here. You may try asking on i.e. xda or other forums

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this.

1. Go to the Settings Page.
2. Go to 'Apps' Settings.
3. Find the app package causing this problem and click into it.
4. Go to 'Permissions' settings and allow all the permissions shown there.
5. Hope the issue is now solved.